# Alternative to RedGate ReadyRoll yet?

Tags: sql, continuous-deployment

I am searching for an affordable alternative to RedGate's ReadyRoll for continuous deployment for SQL.

All of my searches are returning open source projects from nearly a decade ago.

Does anyone have a decent alternative???

Answer (score 4):

Which edition of Visual Studio do you use? If you are fortunate enough to own Visual Studio Enterprise Edition, Redgate (who I work for) has an arrangement with Microsoft to supply [ReadyRoll Core Edition](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/readyroll/entrypage/microsoft-and-readyroll) at part of your entitlement.

If you're using VS Pro or Community then you'll either have to purchase ReadyRoll Pro or you can try one of the open source projects out there. As you point out there are a bunch of OSS projects that are no longer kept up to date, but [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) is the exception and actively maintained. Mind you, unlike ReadyRoll Flyway doesn't generate the migration scripts for you. It simply provides a framework to manage and run unrun migrations scripts that you have authored yourself against your chosen target database.

Note: ReadyRoll Core has been **removed from VS 2019**

Comment: I know it's in your profile, but the general view on meta is that you ought to include affiliation information *within* your answer if your answer deals with your own product(s).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I wasn't aware of this. Is this a new policy? I've been responding to SO questions on Redgate products for years and have checked in the past with SO moderators in the past to double check that my answers have adhered to SO rules.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I've edited the first paragraph accordingly.

Comment: Thanks David. We are on Community right now. I know we have some type of RedGate licenses that we have to look into. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. It just occurred to me that an alternative to Flyway is DbUp. This is also open source. Again, very similar to Flyway except that it's implemented in .NET rather than Java.

Comment: I think the integration with Visual Studio is a big selling point for the team. ReadyRoll seems to be the champ!

Comment: Yes, IDE integration is a strong selling point. The team is actively working on adding SSMS support to ReadyRoll, which is also a highly requested feature.

Comment: Is there a way to buy just ReadyRoll? Last time I checked ReadyRoll was bundled with other tools into a package costing thousands of US dollars.

Comment: @LucasM No, I asked them. They won't sell it separately. It seems to me that Redgate buy up reasonably priced (or even free, see .NET Reflector) tools and, in the case of ReadyRoll, make them prohibitively expensive. Daniel Nolan originally wrote it to solve a common deployment problem and made it available at a reasonable cost. However, he sold out to Redgate (where he secured himself the position of Product Manager) and now they want £2,100+ for it as part of a package of 15! (not even the smaller 11 package) tools I don't want or need.

Comment: @AndyJones You know the history. Again, the words _prohibitively expensive_ are crucial here. However, after using it for few months I must say you get what you pay for. Unfortunately will be switching over to DbUp due to pohibitive cost.

Comment: Please fix typo. ReadyRoll, not ReadyRole. Suggested edit queue is full.

Answer (score 2):

We've been happy just using SQL Server Database projects within Visual Studio, deploying to our databases as needed.  It helps that we're using domain driven design so almost all the tables are built by the C# devs.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [AzureDbUp](https://github.com/TroyWitthoeft/AzureDbUp).
It's DbUp wrapped into a console application for use in your devops pipelines.